# Array with custom indices

Tags: c++, arrays

So I want to create an array of nine elements, but I want the indices to be specified by me, that is, instead of accesing elements of my array,

```
std::array<bool,9> myarray
```

using `myarray[0], myarray[1], myarray[2]...` I want to access them, for example, as

```
myarray[21], myarray[34], myarray[100], myarray[9], myarray[56]...
```

But still conserving the properties of standard library array and storing only 9 elements.

More specifically, I need an easy access to the elements of a boolean matrix.
That is, suppose I have the matrix:

```
Array<array<bool,100>,100> mymatrix;
```

And that it is going to be used for checking certain positions (Say position x,y) easily simply using  `mymatrix[x][y]`. I also know that some of the elements are never going to be checked, so they are not really needed. In order to save the most memory possible, the idea is to get rid of those not needed elements, but still conserving the structure to check my elements.

Comment: Generally it sounds that a better data-structure for your needs may be map. Can you be more specific what _properties of standard library array_ you'd like to conserve?

Comment: Basically memory cost and usage. Main post updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such an array is best represented with one of the associative containers provided by the Standard C++ Library - i.e. either a `std::map<int,bool>` or an `std::unordered_map<int,bool>`. These containers provide an idiomatic way of doing this in C++.

One added benefit of using an associative container is the ability to iterate the values along with their external "indexes".

If you insist on using an array to store the values, you would have to make your own class that builds a "mapping" between external and internal indexes. This would either take a significant amount of memory for an O(1) access time, use CPU cycles for binary search plus an index-to-index map, use linear search, or hard-code the external indexes.

Comment: So, if I have the variables `std::unordered_map<int,bool> mymap` and  `std::array<bool, 100> myarray`, Does `mymap.find(10)` cost the same that `myarray[10]`? I thought it didn't. That's why I wanted to do it as mentioned in my first question.

Comment: @D1X Although the two have identical asymptotic complexities, array lookup is a lot faster. Array, on the other hand, takes more memory, so that's the classic "memory for speed" tradeoff. With 100 elements and a nine-element map it would probably be a wash in terms of memory for a lot more speed, but with values up to 1,000 the map would be smaller.

Comment: So, is it impossible to create exactly what I need and still conserve the array lookup?

Comment: @D1X Right - it's either more CPU, or more memory.

Answer (score 1):

On the first glance, what you want is an `std::map<int, bool>`, which allows you to have your own indices. But, map is not fixed in size.

In order to get both fixed size *and* custom indices, you may combine a map and an array with a custom add and access functions:

```
map<int, bool> indices; // fill it with custom indices mapped onto the array
array<bool, n> data;

bool get(int index) {
    return data[map(index)]
}
```